# Are recursive functions slower than their non recursive counterpart

Tags: c++, recursion

I have used a recursive function for factorial of a number and Fibonacci series (Done in C++) and I have found that the recursive function about factorial runs just normal as expected and execution speeds do not differ greatly.

However on the Fibonacci one it is decisively slow. Why is it so ?

Recursive approach:

```
unsigned long int fib_num(int n)  //This is My code
{
    switch (n)
    {
    case 1:
        return 0;
        break;
    case 2:
        return 1;
        break;
    default:
        return fib_num(n - 1) + fib_num(n - 2);
        break;
    }
}
```

Iterative approach:

```
first = 0;
second = 1

for(i = 0; i < num; i++)   
{
    cout<<"\n"<<first;

    next = first + second;

    first = second;
    second = next;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, we're not mind readers who can immediately determine why one piece of code is slower than the other, without seeing all of the code in question.

Comment: No, recursive functions aren't inherently slow. If you want to know why the two functions have different performance you'll have to show them.

Comment: Recursive Fibonacci is likely to be slow because you recurse twice, and each one recomputes the entire preceding series. Iterative Fibonacci just looks at the two preceding values that were calculated, it doesn't have to go back to the beginning every time.

Comment: So a naive recursive Fibonacci will be O(n^2), while iterative will be O(n).

Comment: You can make the recursive version as fast as the iterative one by using [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)

Comment: It's a good and fair question. I benchmarked both and in every single case the loop-based solution outperformed the recursive ones by some factors! And @Barmar, it's not true what you say - both have the exact same complexity.

Comment: And Barmar for the win.

Comment: @ArmenAvetisyan I made a small mistake. The recursive version is O(2^n). Its call graph looks like a binary tree.

Comment: @Barmar. I don't undestand the comment about O(2^n) could you please help me about it. I understand now why it is slow

Comment: @SuhridMulay Draw the call tree for `fib_num(5)` on a piece of paper, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: `fib_num(5)` makes two calls. They each make two calls, and they each make two calls, until you eventually get to the base of the recursion. So each level doubles the number of calls, which makes it O(2^n)

Comment: @Barmar.  Ah Okay. The function is called till we reach the condition for cases 1 and 2. and since it is being called twice once for (n-1) and the other for (n-2) It will have the shape of 2^n. Which makes it a bit more resource heavy than the for loop. Is my reasoning correct

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Barmar. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation is right, the recursive approach in calculating, in this case, Fibonacci numbers, if you look carefully results in calculation of each and every term of of Fibonacci from the beginning, i.e.

To calculate F[n] + F[n-1], for example, the function calculates both terms separately and it does the same job multiple times.

Example: F[5] = F[4] + F[3]

To calculate F[3] : the program calculates :F[2], F[1], F[1], F[0]

To calculate F[4] : the program calculates again: F[2], F[2], F[1], F[1], F[0], F[0] and F[3]

Here is what your function calls would look like graphically:

[image]

Which leads to your observation, namely, that on each recursive call the amount of work doubles, leading to complexity of: O(2<sup>n</sup>).

---

A possible way to avoid the above is by using memoization:

```
// header needed for the container: map
#include <map> 

int mem_fact (int i, std::map<int, int>& m)
{
    // if value with key == i does not exist in m: calculate it
    if (m.find(i) == m.end()) 
    {
        // the recursive calls are made only if the value doesn't already exist
        m[i] = mem_fact (i - 1, m) + mem_fact (i - 2, m); 
    }

    // if value with key == i exists, return the corresponding value
    return m[i];
}

int fast_factorial (int i)
{
    // key (Fibonacci index) - value (Fibbonaci number)
    std::map<int, int> memo;

    // initialize the first two Fibonacci numbers
    memo.insert(std::pair<int,int>(0, 0));
    memo.insert(std::pair<int,int>(1, 1));

    return mem_fact(i, memo);
}
```

Note: in `main()` you need to call `fast_factorial(num_of_fib)`;

Answer (score 0):

I will give an example of Fibionacci series.

```
recursive 41 index calculated pass time 1.343 seconds
non recursive 40000 index calculated pass time 1.042 seconds
```

here is the code of the ourput.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    long before = new Date().getTime();
    for(int i = 0; i <= 41; i++) {
        findRecursiveFibionacci(i);
    }
    System.out.println("recursive 41 index calculated pass time "+((float)(new Date().getTime()-before)/1000) + " seconds");

    long before2=new Date().getTime();
    for(int i = 0; i <= 40000; i++) {
        getFib(i);
    }
    System.out.println("non recursive40000 index calculated pass time "+((float)(new Date().getTime()-before2)/1000) + " seconds");
}

public static long getFib(final int index) {
    long a=0,b=0,total=0;
    for(int i=0;i<= index;i++) {
        if(i==0) {
            total=a+b;
            a=0;
        }else if(i==1) {
            b=1;
            total=a+b;

        }else if(i%2==0) {
            total=a+b;
            a=total;
        }else {
            total=a+b;
            b=total;
        }
    }
    return total;
}

public static long findRecursiveFibionacci(final int a ){
    if(a==0)return 0;
    if(a<=2)return 1;
    final long fibterm = findRecursiveFibionacci(a-1)+findRecursiveFibionacci(a-2);
    return fibterm;
}
```